In the c++ vector, why cannot we print iterator value individually?
In the following code, I get an error if I type either of the following two

cout << "value of it: " << vec.begin() << endl;


cout << "value of it: " << it << endl;

But if I write following, I do not get error:

cout << "value of it: " << it-Vec.begin() << endl;

Why is that?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main(){

    vector<int> Vec{1, 20, 3, 14, -5, 6, 1, 8, 0, 7 };    
    std::sort(Vec.begin(), Vec.end());
   
    int find_Y = 3;
    auto it = std::lower_bound(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), find_Y);

    cout << "value of it: " << it << endl; // This gives error!!
    cout << "Value of *it: " << *it << endl;
    cout << "Index of Y: " << it - Vec.begin() << endl;   

}


Iterators are black box objects. There is nothing to see inside.

Which error does it give?

An iterator is not an index or an offset, and doesn't generally track its own index or offset (that would be meaningless and/or impractical for containers other than vector - e.g. std::list or std::set). For std::vector, there's an easy way to figure out the index of the element the iterator refers to, if that's what you need; you've already discovered it.

You may think of an iterator as a pointer. Unless you define cout operator << on an iterator, you get a compiler error.
Vec.begin() returns an iterator that points to the first element of Vec.
auto it = std::lower_bound also returns an iterator.
So, it is not surprising that cout << iterator gives an error:
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >')
You can safely dereference Vec.begin() to see the the value, Vec[0].
You can safely dereference the lower_bound return iterator provided that the iterator is not Vec.end().


But if I write following, I do not get error:
cout << "value of it: " << it - Vec.begin() << endl;


Just like in C's pointer arithmetic, you can subtract two iterators. See @Jason R's answer here:
How does subtracting X.begin() return the index of an iterator?
Suppose it points to Vec.begin(), then the difference is 0. If it points to (Vec.begin() + 1), then the difference is 1.
If you are unfamiliar with C pointer arithmetic, please read section, "Pointer arithmetics" here:
https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
Here is your modified program to illustrate the above points:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main(){

    vector<int> Vec{1, 20, 3, 14, -5, 6, 1, 8, 0, 7 };    
    std::sort(Vec.begin(), Vec.end());

    for( auto val:Vec) { cout << val << " "; } std::cout << std::endl; // -5 0 1 1 3 6 7 8 14 20

    cout << "*Vec.begin() = " << *Vec.begin() << ";  *(Vec.end() - 1) = " << *(Vec.end() - 1) << endl; // -5  20
   
    int find_Y = 3;
    auto it = std::lower_bound(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), find_Y);
    // Deference it if allowed
    if( it != Vec.end() )
    {
        // cout << "value of it: " << it << endl; // This gives error!!
        cout << "value of *it: " << *it << endl; // This fixes error.
        cout << "Index of Y: " << it - Vec.begin() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "find_y exceeds max value in Vec" << endl;
        cout << "Index of Y: " << it - Vec.begin() << endl;
    }
}

Output:
-5 0 1 1 3 6 7 8 14 20
*Vec.begin() = -5;  *(Vec.end() - 1) = 20
value of *it: 3
Index of Y: 4

You can change values of find_Y to, say 21, to execute the else condition.
